# UNIX Code explanation at control file creation

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I´am new in UNIX development and i have the following code, i believe is related to a control file but i don't understand it at all, if anyone can explain to me, i'll be very grateful

This is the code

```
ARCH_CTRL_LOCK="$RUTA_CFG/servicioPortabilidad.ctl"
if [ ! -f $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK ]; then 
  (echo "$$" > $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK) 2> /dev/null
else
  PID_GUARDADO=`cat $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK`
  if [ -d /proc/${PID_GUARDADO} ]; then
     echo "Proceso no iniciado, el archivo $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK existe y su PID esta activo ( ${PID_GUARDADO} ), puede estar ejecutandose otra instancia de este proceso."
     exit 2
  fi
  kill -0 ${PID_GUARDADO}  2> /dev/null
  echo ""
  if [ "$?" = "0" ];  then
     echo "Proceso no iniciado, el archivo $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK existe y su PID responde a senhales ( ${PID_GUARDADO} ), puede estar ejecutandose otra instancia de este proceso."
     exit 2
  fi
  (echo "$$" > $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK) 2> /dev/null
fi
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Store the name of the lock file in a variable, so we can use
# it repeatedly.
ARCH_CTRL_LOCK="$RUTA_CFG/servicioPortabilidad.ctl"

# See if the lock file exists.
if [ ! -f $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK ]; then
  # The lock file doesn't exist.

  # Write my own process ID into the file, creating it
  (echo "$$" > $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK) 2> /dev/null

else
  # The lock file DOES exist.

  # Get the process ID from the existing lock file.  This should be
  # the ID of the process that created the lock file.
  PID_GUARDADO=`cat $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK`

  # Looking for a directory named /proc/PID is a way of checking
  # whether that process exists. This only works on operating systems
  # that have a /proc filesystem.  Linux always has /proc, but many
  # other systems (like Mac OS X for example) don't.

  if [ -d /proc/${PID_GUARDADO} ]; then
     # The process still exists.

     # Print an error message.
     echo "Proceso no iniciado, el archivo $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK existe y su PID esta activo ( ${PID_GUARDADO} ), puede estar ejecutandose otra instancia de este proceso."

     # Exit with status 2.
     # All statuses except 0 mean there was an error.
     exit 2
  fi

  # The process doesn't still exist.  But the kill command that
  # follows checks for the process in a different way, that works
  # on any POSIX system.  The kill command exits with status 0
  # (meaning success) if the process exists, and exists with some
  # other status (meaning error) if the process doesn't exist.
  kill -0 ${PID_GUARDADO}  2> /dev/null

  # The following echo command prints a blank line. It also makes
  # the shell forget about the exit status of the kill command.
  echo ""

  # Now see if the exit status from the last command is zero. I
  # guess this was intended to check the exit status of kill, but
  # someone inserted that echo command, which should always exit
  # with status 0, so the test will always pass!
  if [ "$?" = "0" ];  then
     # The exit status of the last command was 0. This should always
     # be the case.  The echo command above should always succeed.

     # Print an error message.
     echo "Proceso no iniciado, el archivo $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK existe y su PID responde a senhales ( ${PID_GUARDADO} ), puede estar ejecutandose otra instancia de este proceso."

     # Exit with status 2.
     exit 2
  fi

  # We can never reach this point, because the echo above should
  # always succeed, so we always print the error message and exit
  # in the previous if statement.

  # Overwrite contents of the lock file with my own process ID.
  (echo "$$" > $ARCH_CTRL_LOCK) 2> /dev/null
fi
```

[Technically](http://xkcd.com/1475/), the `echo ""` command can fail, but only if standard output has been closed, or redirected to a file on a full filesystem, or in some other way set up so that it's unwritable.  That's very unlikely.

Comment: This is a great lesson in how to approach figuring out code you don't know.  As you learn what it does, add the comments. Go back and add a summary of what the section of code as a whole does.  Bugs may be discovered during the process that identify the reason of why you are investigating this in the first place.  Then, learn from this and write your code with comments in the first place!  If the original author did this, you would not have spent who knows how long figuring it out.  Remember to code for the person maintaining this after you, who may not be as experienced.